# How to implement autocomplete for address field using google places/maps api?

Tags: ajax, location

When using Eventbrite event creating form, i noticed their address field has an autocomplete feature powered by Google.
Is there a Drupal module that does something similar ?

---

[image: Autocomplete]

---

[Demo link on Google Code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

Comment: Any ideas are welcome .. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have created a working sandbox version of address autocomplete. https://drupal.org/sandbox/adammitchell/2126989. I will endeavour to get it created into a full blown project. However if you could help me and test it that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten more attention for this answer/module. This is a great project. Thank you.